# solace v2 semp java sample code dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, solace, solace-mq

I am trying to get this sample code to compile https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-semp/tree/master/java

I have done the gradle build command as instructed but the sample code still cannot find the com.solace.labs.sempclient dependencies for e.g. inside ManageVPN.java:

```
  import com.solace.labs.sempclient.samplelib.ApiClient;
  import com.solace.labs.sempclient.samplelib.ApiException;
  import com.solace.labs.sempclient.samplelib.api.MsgVpnApi;
  import com.solace.labs.sempclient.samplelib.model.MsgVpn;
```

I am sitting behind a corporate FW so it could be that gradle failed to get these from some central repo so can some one please tell me which jars to get which I can put on my path manually please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So finally got it working by using my office proxy with command:

C:\solace-samples-semp-master\java>..\gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=workplace proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=your office username that the proxy would accept  -Dhttps.proxyPassword=your pw